# Assembly language for the 8086 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, emu8086

Hello kind people from stackoverflow.So i am a 'greenhorn' in the assembly language, but i love programming and I am ambitious, so eventually i will master assembly too, but until then i need your help with a problem.
**So, i have to write a program for the 8086 microprocessor, that finds all the factors(divisors) of a given number**, I searched the internet but the results were to complicated for me at this point to understand. So me & my brain wrote the program in C but now my brain doesn't know how to traslate that to assembly language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number, i;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    printf("The divisors(factors) for %d are: ", number);
    for(i = 0; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
           printf("%d", i);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

So, how do i do this in assambly?
This is how much did by now, but probably it's just bad code:

```
Date:

number dw 54 ;dw because I work with 16 bits
i      dw 2
result dw ? ; the actual result

CODE:

mov ax, number ; I move the value of number in ax(16 bits)
mov bx, i

loop:
div bx ; number % i
cmp bx, 0; compare the modulo with 0
je final ; jump to final if is true
mov dx, 0
mov ax, bx
mov bx, dx
jmp loop ; jump from loop

;So...what now?...      

final:

move result, ax;move what i have in ax to result

move ax, 4C00h ; i really don't know what is this...i just know i has to be at the end
int 21h ; an integer
```

Please, can you help me?
Note: I tried to install TASM to test my code but it didn't work, i have a feeling that it works only for windows 7, but i am not sure.So, i need you tell me if the code is good or bad.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You're getting an error? Add the error message to your post. Your code isn't doing what you expect? What is it doing? What did you expect? Please read [Why is “can someone help me?” not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: Look, I sad this  "So, i have to write a program for the 8086 microprocessor, that finds all the factors(divisors) of a given number", I have the code in C, but i have no clue how to do that in assembly language. I don't even know if what i did is wrong or good, because i don't have a TASM(it doesn't work on my operating).

Comment: *"but it didn't work"* isn't the best description of the problem you have. Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: Look sir, I don't know what you mean by "Could you be a bit more precise?", I told you what my problem is,I don't know how can I be more precise, I just want someone to tell me if what i did is good or bad, and if it's bad, to help me make it good.

Comment: `i`' should start at 2. 0 should cause divide overflow, and I don't think the assignment wants to report 1 as a factor.

Comment: What are you using for a 16 bit (real mode) assembler, and what operating system are you using (64 bit windows can't run 16 bit real mode code, but a virtual machine or perhaps DOSBOX would work)?

Comment: I am using windows10 x64, i don't have a compiler for my assemlbly code.I tried to install TASM, but it doesn't like my operating system(i believe it runs on windows 7). So... long story short, i write my code on paper. I will try to put a linux distribution on virtual box, to see if i can convert my code from C to assemly.

Comment: Turbo Assembler was great in its day, but it hasn't been updated since the '90s, and it definitely won't work on a 64-bit PC without emulation or virtualization. You may want to consider using newer tools than TASM.  Microsoft Macro Assembler (MASM) is now free, as is the Netwide Assembler (NASM), as is the GNU Assembler (GAS), among others.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest you to start with finding the smallest divisor. Because as I see above you are going to final label when modulo is zero. So when it finds a divisor it will jump there and finish.

And my second advice, when you are working on MUL and DIV instruction, use them carefully. When you do DIV BX modulo will not be on BX. It will be on DX. Because your divisor is 16-bit(which is BX). So 8086 will do DX:AX/BX with quo:AX and Remainder:DX(modulo).

Like I said if you are new you should practice on easier applications on DIV and MUL first.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, i will remember your advice.